# properties file for vagrant and puppet

Tags: sdk, puppet, vagrant

I am in the process of creating a company-internal SDK for a set of systems we are building.
We have multiple stages, such as "development", "quality-assurance" and "production" were we host the real services.

I'd like the SDK to be able to mirror these stages. For that I'd like to use vagrant, puppet and some kind of property file which contains the versions of the services that match the stages.

Is it possible to have such an external file? All it defines are a couple of variables for the versions.
Everything else (nodes, network, applications, WAR-files, DBs, etc) should be defined in a generic vagrant/puppet file.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [hiera](https://puppetlabs.com/blog/first-look-installing-and-using-hiera/), it's a hierarchical data structure for puppet parameters, it enables setting different parameter values for different environments (dev, test & prod).

Starting from puppet3 hiera is built into puppet (make sure the puppet client on your vagrant box is > 3, run: puppet -V)